# Grails, MySQL (MariaDB) - max_allowed_packet exceeded despite less data

Tags: mysql, grails, mariadb

Currently I'm developing a grails project and therefore I'm using XAMPP 5.6.14 locally. I now run into the following problem:

```
Packet for query is too large (10485896 > 10485760). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

Before that error occurred I altered the configuration of my.cnf as follows:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 10M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 400M
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
```

The domain class I want to have saved in the database looks like the following:

```
class DocumentFile {

    Date dateCreated
    Timestamp timestamp
    Integer someValue
    String someOtherValue
    Blob file

    static constraints = {
        someValue nullable: true
        someOtherValue nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        file type: 'blob'
    }
}
```

For test reasons I used the following lines to insert a new file into the database:

```
def file = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(file.getBytes())
sql.execute("insert into tblDocumentFile (dateCreated, timestamp, file, someOtherValue, someValue) values (NOW(), NOW(), ?, ?, ?)", [file, 'someValue', 1])
```

So far so good. The problem is - the error message above is presented when the file size is exactly 5242880 Bytes. And that's where I'm stuck.

Why do I get that error message when my file is exactly the half of `max_allowed_packet`?
Why is the packet for query obviously doubled in size?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packet size as reported by the database is not equal to the data size as you have in your object. There can be a significant difference due to double byte character encoding (can be 100% difference in size) and due to some overhead (up to 10% on the size after the character encoding has been taken into account).

Comment: Or `BLOBs` are transferred in HEX?

Comment: You hint was worth gold! I created the test file using the command `dd if=/dev/zero of=file_5M.txt bs=1 count=0 seek=5M`. The file size was 5M as expected. However, saving that file MySQL needed two bytes for each character. I tried with a 5M file full of "a" and it worked like a charm. Eventually, I increased `max_allowed_packet` and the other parameters according to the character set used (utf8mb4_unicode_ci). Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks! It is not just MySQL suffering from this: Try any other relational DBMS and you can run in the same issues.